# Spring: @Component

Tags: java, spring

Spring documentation defines @Component annotation in the following way: "Indicates that an annotated class is a "component". Such classes are considered as candidates for auto-detection when using annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning. "

This is concise, but it does not say a lot. I understand that @Component is used to indicate that a class lifecycle (creation/destruction) will be managed by Spring. The question I have: I need to use it only in classes that will be autowired somewhere (1) or do I also need to use it in classes that have autowired attributes (2)?

(1)

```
@Component
class B {
}

class A {

   // @Autowired
   B b;
}
```

(2)

```
@Component
class B {
}

@Component
class A {

  // @Autowired
  B b;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, strictly speaking you don't have to use anywhere, you can define beans in XML like in the old days. Also you can use `@Service` or `@Repository` like in the old days. But back to your question:

If your bean `A` is not annotated with `@Component` or otherwise known to the Spring context, it will never be created and managed by Spring. So you either have to use an annotation or define `A` in XML.

This is true for `B` as well. If you want it to be a subject for autowiring, it must be known to Spring - either by annotation scanning or by XML.

At the end of the day it doesn't really matter whether you use XML, annotation or Java configuration. It's important that both beans are known to application context.

Comment: I only use annotations (not XML) to register objects in the application context. I'll rewrite my question: if objects of class A are only created manually (and considering class A has autowired attributes), does it need to be known to the application context (independent if this is done via xml or annotations)?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: of course. If you simply do `A a = new A`, has is Spring suppose to know about this `a` instance and the fact that it has `@Autowired` fields? It must be instantiated by Spring.